# How to get array from json response in angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, json, angularjs, getjson

I am trying to get the array data in a JSON response. The following is my JSON response and I need to get `date` and `stallNo` from the `data` array.

```js
{
    "operation": "AnodeSet",
    "stageMap": {
        "stop": 5, 
        "adders": 4
        // ...
    },
    "anodeProb": [
        { 
            "name": "hello", 
            "index" : "hii" 
        }
    ],
    "data" : [
        { 
            "operation" : "AnodeSet", 
            "stallNo: 7", 
            "date" : "21/12/2015" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is always only 1 element returned in the `data` array you can retrieve it by index:

```
var date = json.data[0].date;
var stallNo = json.data[0].stallNo;
```

If there could be multiple elements in the array you would need to loop over them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    var date = json.data[i].date;
    var stallNo = json.data[i].stallNo;

    // use the above values as required...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for angularjs solution then you can use `angular.forEach`:

```
angular.forEach(json.data, function(item, key) {
  console.log(item.stallNo);
  console.log(item.date);
});
```

use the above one if you have more than one objects in your response. Although works for single objec too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's very simple

suppose response in an object

```
var object={
    "operation": "AnodeSet",
    "stageMap": {
        "stop": 5, 
        "adders": 4
        // ...
    },
    "anodeProb": [
        { "name": "hello", "index" : "hii" }
    ],
    "data" : [
        { "operation" : "AnodeSet", "stallNo: 7", "date" : "21/12/2015" }
    ]
}
```

Then you need to track your requirement:-

```
object-->

       -->data(array)

                   -->index[0,1,2.....n]

                                      -->Keys you want.

var date = object.date[0].date;
var stallNo = object.date[0].stallNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method from underscore.js like below, [Link for reference](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
 _.pluck(yourObject.data, 'stallNo');

 _.pluck(yourObject.data, 'date');
```

Output will be [7,10,12, ...], [21/12/2015, ...](until length of your data object)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your JSON is not parsed string.

```
var JSONstr='{\
    "operation": "AnodeSet",\
    "stageMap": {\
        "stop": 5, \
        "adders": 4\
    },\
    "anodeProb": [\
        { \
            "name": "hello", \
            "index" : "hii" \
        }\
    ],\
    "data" : [\
        { \
            "operation" : "AnodeSet", \
            "stallNo": 7, \
            "date" : "21/12/2015" \
        }\
    ]\
}';
var obj = JSON.parse(JSONstr);
console.log(obj.data[0].date, obj.data[0].stallNo);
```

You can use my sandbox for check to check how it works: http://jsbin.com/xugahatiwo/1/edit?js,console

Greets

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(json.data, function(value) {
      console.log(value.date);
      console.log(value.stallNo);
});
```